# How to select table colums using wildcards

Tags: sqlite, tcl

Having a SQLite table with a column containing names:

```
Names

ThingA_1
ThingF_1
ThingF_2
ThingB_1
ThingB_2
ThingB_3
ThingB_4
```

I would like to remove all rows containing "ThingF_*"
I could loop over the whole table using the Standard DELETE FROM command:

```
DB eval { DELETE FROM 'MyTable' WHERE Names = 'ThingF_1' }
DB eval { DELETE FROM 'MyTable' WHERE Names = 'ThingF_2' }
```

I have tried the LIKE command but with no success (and no error message)

```
set Name ThingF_

DB eval { DELETE FROM 'MyTable' WHERE Names LIKE $Name }
```

I also tried

```
DB eval { DELETE FROM 'MyTable' WHERE Names LIKE '$Name%' }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This *almost* works:

```
set Name ThingF_
DB eval { DELETE FROM 'MyTable' WHERE Names LIKE $Name }
```

The only problems are that you're passing a pattern that doesn't match, and you're looking to match `_` which is an [SQL `LIKE` single-character wildcard](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp). Because of that, you'd be better off using a glob match (an SQLite-specific extension, but a useful one here). You can use:

```
set NamePattern "ThingF_*"
DB eval { DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE Names GLOB :NamePattern }
```

or (`||` is the SQL string concatenation operator; if you want to do concatenation in the SQL engine, you need to ask for it explicitly, unlike in Tcl):

```
set Name "ThingF_"
DB eval { DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE Names GLOB (:Name || '*') }
```

---

### General Style Notes

I've stopped quoting `MyTable` as a string literal. If you need to quote your token names, use `"this"` or `[this]` or `` `this` ``, but definitely not `"this"` which only works as a compatibility shim and is really discouraged in good SQL code. Also, I've switched the `$Name` to `:Name` for named parameters; while the SQL is in braces and so it is perfectly OK to use `$Name`, it still feels a little too close to being an accident waiting to happen and `:Name` is much more clearly a parameter and not a standard Tcl variable (though it is bound as such by default).

Comment: The `$Name` syntax is what makes Sqlite in Tcl feel like you are still writing Tcl. See also https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#varparam.

Comment: Thank you very much Donal! I actually never realised that $something within the SQL Statement not is an TCL variable.

Answer (score 0):

User either LIKE or GLOB):

```
... WHERE Names LIKE 'ThingF_%'
... WHERE Names GLOB 'ThingF_*'
```

Only GLOB is case sensitive.